# Extract the last part of a facebook page url

Tags: python, regex, url, entity

Let's say we have different links for facebook pages. I want to extract the 'entity' in these links. For example:

In http://www.facebook.com/pages/Blue-Mountain-Aromatics/561694213861926
I want to extract 'Blue-Mountain-Aromatics'.

In http://www.facebook.com/1905BocaJuniors I want to extract '1905BocaJuniors'.

In https://www.facebook.com/7upGuatemala?ref=br_tf I want to extract '7upGuatemala'

In http://www.fb.com/supligenjm I want to extract 'supligenjm'

In http://www.facebook.com/axebolivia?sk=wall&filter=1 I want to extract 'axebolivia'

I have tried with many if-else statements in order to brake it down but in  the end of the day it's just spaghetti code.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you have already created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    from urlparse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse

links = [
    'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Blue-Mountain-Aromatics/561694213861926',
    'http://www.facebook.com/1905BocaJuniors',
    'https://www.facebook.com/7upGuatemala?ref=br_tf',
    'http://www.fb.com/supligenjm',
    'http://www.facebook.com/axebolivia?sk=wall&filter=1',
]


for url in links:
    url = urlparse(url)
    path = url.path.split('/')
    entity = path[2] if path[1] == 'pages' else path[1]
    print(entity)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python 3 version of @Robᵩs answer (and re-written to a funtion):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

links = [
    'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Blue-Mountain-Aromatics/561694213861926',
    'http://www.facebook.com/1905BocaJuniors',
    'https://www.facebook.com/7upGuatemala?ref=br_tf',
    'http://www.fb.com/supligenjm',
    'http://www.facebook.com/axebolivia?sk=wall&filter=1',
]

def fb_extract(url):
    url = urlparse(url)
    path = url.path.split('/')
    entity = path[2] if path[1] == 'pages' else path[1]
    return entity

for url in links:
    fb_extract(url)
```

Hope this helps!